# Populate SQL column with days of the week within a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, command

I currently have a table in my database which lists a range of dates, going from May until October, in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

What I would like to do is create a new column with the days of the week, matching the date. I thought of two options;

1. Update all rows, in column 'day', starting with monday, then the next tuesday, next wednesday, etc, etc. and when reached sunday, loop the sequence until end of table.
2. Read the date in column 'date' and update the column 'day' with the matching day of the week.

I think option 1 is the most easy, and very well possible, because there are no dates being skipped. But I have no idea how to do this and couldn't find anything similar searching the web.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: @echo_me Thnx for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, I would say: don't do it. The day of the week is derived directly from the date; storing it separately in the database breaks one of the basic rules of normalisation (no derived data).

There are MySQL functions to find the day of the week - dayofweek() and weekday().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table
set day = DATENAME(dw, date)
```